# What is the net gain of charge carriers in a semiconductor if an atom is removed?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-chemistry, conductivity, semiconductors, electrical-properties

In pure germanium, all Ge atoms are bonded with a tetrahedral geometry. It has a band gap and is a semiconductor. If we remove one Ge atom, what type(s) and how many charge carriers will be generated? So far the explanation I have found is, by removing one Ge atom, 4 electrons from the valence band is removed, which is equivalent to say 4 holes have been added to the valence band. Hence, the answer is a net gain of 4 holes as charge carriers.

But we still have four non-bonding electrons left (from the 4 neighbouring Ge atoms): where do they go? Are they simply equivalent to the newly generated 4 holes or they should be counted separately? And by removing that Ge, four orbitals are removed as well, which I think would change both valence and conduction bands.

However, another contradictory scenario is for graphite: if we remove one carbon, what type(s) and how many charge carriers will be generated? If using the same rationale, 4 electrons from the filled band is removed, so we should expect a net gain of 4 holes as well? But considering the special band structure of graphite, perhaps only 1 hole is generated in the valence band, as $p_z$ is higher than $sp^2$ orbitals. But the suggested explanation is: we are removing 1 electron from the valence band and there are 3 more non-bonding ones generated, so there is a net gain of 2 electrons into the conduction band.

Or, trying to make the two situations agree, could it be that these net gain of 2 electrons equivalent to 2 holes? But it seems not very convincing.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Comment: From https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.035203 one finds that there are various possible charge states for the germanium vacancy, with different levels ranging from inside the valance band to just below the conduction band. The occupancy of such states depends on where the Fermi energy is. Now, your thought process is very molecular-bonding like, not solid state physics like, so you are being led astray by it.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for your reply and really sorry that it is from a second year undergraduate chemistry course, so my reasoning is confined to the tight binding model, band structures, etc.... But many thanks for sharing the paper.